# VBA doesn't display any Runtime error message

Tags: excel, vba

So I was trying to do some error handlings and ran a procedure to add a sheet if existing like

```
Sub procedure1 ()
    ...
    Application.DisplayAlterts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(“Inexisting sheet“).delete
    Application.DisplayAlterts = True

    Sheets("Inexisting sheet").Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)
End sub
```

After running the procedures I found that VBA no longer shows any runtime error.

I tested the following code and expected the default runtime error message:

```
Sub test()
    Application.DisplayAlterts = True
    'On Error GoTo Dummy
    MsgBox(10/0)  'no error message 
    MsgBox("end") 'not reached

Dummy:
    MsgBox("err") 'this works when On Error statement is not commented out
End Sub
```

When I commented out the On Error statement, no error messages nor message box pops up. It seems that VBA just ended the sub when hitting an error, without displaying the default error message which has a "debug" button.

I'm new to error handling so I have no idea what's happening here. Thanks in advance for any helps and solutions

Comment: Did you call `test` separately or within `procedure1`?

Comment: `DisplayAlterts` will not compile, so it's unlikely you ran that `test` code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub procedure1()
    ...
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Inexisting sheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling to default
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Sheets("Inexisting sheet").Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets("Inexisting sheet").Add` did you try running your code?